# R - How can I combine values across multiple columns in a pairwise matching fashion, possibly using 'mutate' or 'coalesce'?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset taken from a large survey that consists of ~2k participants (rows) and some 160 variables (columns). The relevant columns include the following:

- participant IDS
- cl.exp which is a "yes"/"no" response
- cl.yes.Q1 up to cl.yes.Q7 which have values if the participant answered "yes" to cl.exp, and NA if they answered "no" to cl.exp
- cl.no.Q1 up to cl.no.Q7 which have values if the participant answered "no" to cl.exp, and NA if they answered "yes" to cl.exp

The questions for both cl.exp "yes" and "no" are synonymous, with the exception that no.Q6 and no.Q7 are the inverse of yes.Q6 and yes.Q7; i.e., no.Q7 is synonymous with yes.Q6 and no.Q6 is synonymous with yes.Q7.

The first few rows could be as follows:

| ID | cl.exp | cl.yes.Q1 | cl.yes.Q2 | cl.yes.Q3 | cl.yes.Q4 | cl.yes.Q5 | cl.yes.Q6 | cl.yes.Q7 | cl.no.Q1 | cl.no.Q2 | cl.no.Q3 | cl.no.Q4 | cl.no.Q5 | cl.no.Q6 | cl.no.Q7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | No | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 2 | 6 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 7 | 4 |
| 2 | No | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 3 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 5 | 7 | 3 |
| 3 | Yes | 2 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 4 | 2 | 7 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 4 | Yes | 7 | 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 2 | 5 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |

You'll notice that participants either have values in cl.yes.Q1-7 or cl.no.Q1-7, but never both. I'd like to do either one of the following: a) move the values from cl.no.Q1-7 into the respective columns of cl.yes.Q1-7, or b) create new columns that combine the appropriate columns from cl.yes and cl.no, i.e., cl.yes.Q1 and cl.no.Q1, cl.yes.Q2 and cl.no.Q2, and so on.

I solve the no.Q6 and no.Q7 reverse issue by using the following code:

```
df[15:16] <- df[16:15]
```

I then do the following:

```
df.yes <- df %>% 
             select(contains("cl.yes"), id, cl.exp)  %>%
             drop_na()

df.no <- df %>% 
             select(contains("cl.no"), id, cl.exp)  %>%
             drop_na()

names(df.yes) <- gsub("cl.yes.", "cl.", names(df.yes))
names(df.no) <- gsub("cl.no.", "cl.", names(df.no))
df.cl <- merge(df.yes, df.no, all = TRUE)
```

This gives me a new dataframe that has the merged columns. However, I believe there must be a simpler/cleaner/more elegant solution than this, particularly with the ability to keep the data in the original dataframe. I tried some iterations with mutate and coalesce and could never succeed. If anyone has a one or two line code that basically does the same thing that I did here, I would greatly appreciate your insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution use a for loop to dynamically `coalesce` the column ending with the same question numbers. You will need to know the last question number to write down the iterator of the for loop.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>% select(ID, cl.exp)

for (i in 1:7){
  temp <- dat %>% 
    select(ends_with(paste0("Q", i))) %>%
    as.list()
  
  dat2[[paste0("cl.Q", i)]] <- coalesce(!!!temp)
}

dat2
#   ID cl.exp cl.Q1 cl.Q2 cl.Q3 cl.Q4 cl.Q5 cl.Q6 cl.Q7
# 1  1     No     2     6     3     4     3     7     4
# 2  2     No     3     6     6     6     5     7     3
# 3  3    Yes     2     5     6     6     4     2     7
# 4  4    Yes     7     1     5     6     7     2     5
```

Note: I did not swap Q6 and Q7, but I am sure you have figured the best way to do it.

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID    cl.exp  cl.yes.Q1   cl.yes.Q2   cl.yes.Q3   cl.yes.Q4   cl.yes.Q5   cl.yes.Q6   cl.yes.Q7   cl.no.Q1    cl.no.Q2    cl.no.Q3    cl.no.Q4    cl.no.Q5    cl.no.Q6    cl.no.Q7
1   No  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  2   6   3   4   3   7   4
2   No  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  3   6   6   6   5   7   3
3   Yes 2   5   6   6   4   2   7   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
4   Yes 7   1   5   6   7   2   5   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA",
                  header = TRUE)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Simple, clean, elegant. One question: what does the '!!!' mean/do in your last statement?

Comment: @kashdollaz This is a special operator from the `rlang` package called splice operator. See the documentation of `rlang` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- tibble::tribble(~ID, ~cl.exp, ~cl.yes.Q1, ~cl.yes.Q2, ~cl.yes.Q3, ~cl.yes.Q4, ~cl.yes.Q5, ~cl.yes.Q6, ~cl.yes.Q7, ~cl.no.Q1, ~cl.no.Q2, ~cl.no.Q3, ~cl.no.Q4, ~cl.no.Q5, ~cl.no.Q6, ~cl.no.Q7, 
1, "No",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,6,3,4,3,7,4,
2, "Yes",3,6,6,6,5,7,3, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)

bind_cols(dat %>% select(c(ID, cl.exp)), 
          coalesce(dat %>% 
                     select(contains("no")) %>% 
                     setNames(gsub("\\.no", "", names(.))), 
                   dat %>% 
                     select(contains("yes"))%>% 
                     setNames(gsub("\\.yes", "", names(.)))))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 9
#>      ID cl.exp cl.Q1 cl.Q2 cl.Q3 cl.Q4 cl.Q5 cl.Q6 cl.Q7
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 No         2     6     3     4     3     7     4
#> 2     2 Yes        3     6     6     6     5     7     3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This one works fairly nicely! It pulls the columns out into a new dataframe that I have to merge back in (not that big a deal), but for some reason it also pulls a couple unrelated columns in the full dataset with it. The column names have no relation to the important variables and I can't see how they were selected based on the code or naming scheme. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this one:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID, cl.exp), 
               names_to = c('.value', 'name'), 
               names_pattern = '(.*)(\\d+)') %>% 
  mutate(cl.yes.Q = coalesce(cl.yes.Q, cl.no.Q), .keep="unused") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = cl.yes.Q)
```

```
     ID cl.exp   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`
  <int> <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1 No         2     6     3     4     3     7     4
2     2 No         3     6     6     6     5     7     3
3     3 Yes        2     5     6     6     4     2     7
4     4 Yes        7     1     5     6     7     2     5
```

Comment: This sort of works - if I try to apply it to my full dataset then it starts trying to act on other columns and comes up with an error. I had to add in the following line to make it work:
`df %>% select(contains("cl."), ID, cl.exp) %>%`
Unfortunately that leaves me with the same issue, that it's now a separate dataset I have to merge back in. A little cleaner than my initial solution, though! Thank you for the input!

Comment: If the data are grouped then the grouping variables will come along for the ride.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `mutate` and `coalesce` like so (after swapping `no.Q6` and `no.Q7` as you did above):

```
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>% mutate(cl.Q1 = coalesce(cl.yes.Q1, cl.no.Q1), 
                        cl.Q2 = coalesce(cl.yes.Q2, cl.no.Q2), 
                        cl.Q3 = coalesce(cl.yes.Q3, cl.no.Q3), 
                        cl.Q4 = coalesce(cl.yes.Q4, cl.no.Q4), 
                        cl.Q5 = coalesce(cl.yes.Q5, cl.no.Q5), 
                        cl.Q6 = coalesce(cl.yes.Q6, cl.no.Q6), 
                        cl.Q7 = coalesce(cl.yes.Q7, cl.no.Q7)) %>%
                 select(-(cl.yes.Q1:cl.no.Q7))
```

We simply use `mutate` to create the `cl.Q*` columns coalescing the values from the `cl.yes.Q*` and `cl.no.Q*` columns, respectively. Then, we remove the original `cl.yes.Q*` and `cl.no.Q*` columns using `select`.

Comment: Thank you, this is great! I like how straightforward and easy to interpret this one is. One issue I see though is the code becomes a bit lengthy as numbers of columns increases - here we thankfully only have 7 to match. Thank you for the suggestion!